# How to run my node app alongside my php application

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've been playing around with nginx and reverse proxy's to try figure out how to run my nodejs app alongside my php application. The node app is just a simple socket io chat app but i'd like it to run on chat.mydomain.com. Would someone be able to guide me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [NGINX server blocks](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/).
You can create one proxy for your php app on `yourdomain.com` and another one for `chat.yourdomain.com` which points to your node app.